# How can I write an if else statement in Twig based on commerce stock quantity?

Tags: theming, commerce

Building a D8 Commerce site and trying to hide the price if the product is out of stock.
I can access the stock value with this:

```
{{ product.variation_field_stock_level.0 }}
```

I've tried this:

```
{% if product.variation_field_stock_level.0 > 0 %}
 {{ product.variation_price }}
{% else %}
 <p>Sold</p>
{% endif %}
```

...but it prints the price regardless of whether the stock value is 0 or 1 (or more).
I've also tried:

```
{% if product.variation_field_stock_level.0 == 0 %}
  <p>Sold</p>
{% else %}
  {{ product.variation_price }}
{% endif %}
```

Regardless of what I try it just will not work.

Comment: What template file are you using? Are you sure the template file is being read?

Comment: I'm using the standard commerce product template
commerce-product.html.twig
I can see the value for the stock level printed on the front end, but the template won't do that calculations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very close - but it seems you are missing the actual stock level value from the object. Start by doing something like:

```
{{product.variation_field_stock_level.0|json_encode}}
```

Run it through a json cleaner to make it readable, like: [JSON Cleaner](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

You will see this:

```
{"#type":"html_tag","#tag":"p","#value":0}
```

Now the conditional will be:

```
{% if product.variation_field_stock_level.0['#value'] > 0 %}
    {{ product.variation_price }}
{% else %}
    <p>Sold</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I would also recommend writing this logic inside of a preprocess function instead of TWIG. The question was specifically how to do this in TWIG - so the answer reflects that.

Comment: You're correct. With the additional |json_encode I got this:
{"#type":"html_tag","#tag":"p","#value":0}
So the answer is to use {{ product.variation_field_stock_level.0['#value'] }}

Comment: Awesome! I'll update the answer to reflect the `[#value]` bit.